# Data Factory cannot copy `csv` with comma after last column to sql data warehouse

Tags: azure, csv, azure-data-factory

I have `CSV` files that I want to copy from a blob to DW, the `CSV` files have comma after the last column (see example below). Using ADF, I tried to copy csv files to a SQL table in DW. However, I got this error, which I think it's because of the last comma (as I have 15 columns):

[image]

few rows of csv file:

```
Code,Last Trading Date,Bid Price,Bid Size,Ask Price,Ask Size,Last Price,Traded Volume,Open Price,High Price,Low Price,Settlement Price,Settlement Date,Implied Volatility,Last Trade Time,
BNH2021F,31/03/2021,37.750000,1,38.000000,1,,0,,,,37.750000,29/03/2021,,,
BNM2021F,30/06/2021,44.500000,6,44.700000,2,44.400000,4,44.300000,44.400000,44.300000,44.500000,29/03/2021,,15-55-47.000,
BNU2021F,30/09/2021,46.250000,2,47.000000,1,47.490000,2,47.490000,47.490000,47.490000,46.920000,29/03/2021,,15-59-10.000,
```

Note that `CSV`s are the original files and I can't change them. I also tried different *Quote* and *Escape* characters in the dataset and it didn't work.
Also I want to do this using ADF, not azure functions.

I couldn't find any solution to that, please help.

**Update**:
It's interesting that the dataset preview works:
[image]

Comment: Hey @mas,
Since you have a SQL DW as the sink, you can use an External table polybase to read the blob file and via ADF leverage the external table to copy data.
In case of a CSV, an additional column at the end would fail your SQL DW select query

Comment: thanks but this is the answer to a different question

Comment: Generally speaking, the end of the CSV in the blob cannot be a comma, and adf will interpret it as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use data flow to achieve that.

1. Azure data factory will interpret last comma as a column with null value. So we can use Select activity to filter last column.
   [image]
2. Set mapping manually at **sink**.
   [image]
3. Then we can sink to our DW or SQL table.
   [image]

Comment: good solution, thanks! But I still have one issue "Linked service with Self-hosted Integration runtime is not supported in data flow." Our connection to storage account is through a Vnet :(

Comment: The Data Flow source dataset must use a Linked Service that uses an Azure IR, not a self-hosted IR. :(

Comment: yep, that's my issue. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You are using 15 columns and your destination is expecting 16. Add another column to your CSV or modify your DW.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution to this.

**Step 1:**

Uncheck the "First Row as header" option in your source dataset
[image]

**Step 2:** Sink it first to another CSV file. in the sink csv dataset import schema like below. Copy activity will create a new CSV file with all clean 15 columns i.e. last extra comma will not be present in new csv file.

[image: Click here to see image of mapping setting]

**Step 3:** Copy from the newly created csv file with "First row as header"  checked and sick it to DW.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the last column from a csv file being empty
col1,col2,col3

"a","b",

"c","d",

The pipeline is dynamic so I can't do manual mapping.

In my case, I solved the issue by replacing  NULL value in the dataset with ""